# Проблема с передачей матрицы в функцию

Tags: c++

В интернет искал ответ на свой вопрос, но не один из способов не работал.

Можете исправить и объяснить почему у меня так не работает?

Ошибка:

main.cpp:3:58: ошибка: use of parameter outside function body before «]» token
 void print_array(int wight, int height, int vmatrix[wight][height])
                                                          ^
main.cpp:3:66: ошибка: use of parameter outside function body before «]» token
 void print_array(int wight, int height, int vmatrix[wight][height])

Код:

```
#include <iostream>

void print_array(int wight, int height, int matrix[wight][height])
{
    std::cout << "";
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    int wight, height;

    std::cout << "Введите размер матрицы: ";
    std::cin >> wight >> height;

    /* Проверка */
    if (wight < 1 || height < 1)
    {
        std::cout << "Ошибка. Матрица такой не может быть" << '\n';
        return 1;
    }

    int matrix[wight][height];

    std::cout << "Введите данные для этой матрицы" << std::endl;

    for (int index_1 = 0; index_1 < wight; index_1++)
    {
        for (int index_2 = 0; index_2 < height; index_2++)
        {
            std::cin >> matrix[index_1][index_2];
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Матрица получилась: " << '\n';

    print_array(wight, height, matrix);

    return 0;
}
```

Версия компилятора:
g++ (GCC) 8.2.1 20181127

Comment: Передать в функцию вы можете `int matrix[wight][height]` только если `wight` и `height` - константы времени компиляции. В крайнем случае - `int matrix[][height]`. Но передавать так массив, размеры которого становятся известны при выполнении - нельзя...

Comment: Язык С++ не позволяет объявлять массивы неконстантного размера. Ни о каком `int matrix[wight][height]` не может быть и речи. Такое возможно только в С.

Comment: @AnT так как это переделать?

Comment: Просто воспользуйтесь `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.

Comment: Или передавайте одномерный массив размера `width * height`.

Comment: @Harry, нельзя даже  int matrix[][height].  Другое дело, если  height    аргумент шалона или определен до обьявления функции,  как константа

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Читаем "*только если wight и height - константы времени компиляции*". С чего вы решили, что я отменил свое же примечание? Все, что я написал - что в крайнем случае можно убрать одну константу времени компиляции.

Comment: @Harry,   Ваши слова   "В крайнем случае..." ввели меня в заблуждение

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Да ничего страшного, главное, что все утрясли :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не хотите `vector<vector<int>>`, можно выделять матрицу динамически. Только вот обычно матрицы записываются построчно, а не постолбцово, как у вас. Матрица 5x6 - это пять строк по 6 элементов.

Вот решение с динамическим выделением матрицы:

```
void print_array(int width, int height, int ** matrix)
{
    for (int index_1 = 0; index_1 < height; index_1++)
    {
        for (int index_2 = 0; index_2 < width; index_2++)
        {
            std::cout << matrix[index_1][index_2] << "  ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    int width, height;

    std::cout << "Введите размер матрицы: ";
    std::cin >> height >> width;

    /* Проверка */
    if (width < 1 || height < 1)
    {
        std::cout << "Ошибка. Матрица такой не может быть" << '\n';
        return 1;
    }

    int ** matrix = new int*[height];
    for(int i = 0; i < height; ++ i)
        matrix[i] = new int[width];

    std::cout << "Введите данные для этой матрицы" << std::endl;

    for (int index_1 = 0; index_1 < height; index_1++)
    {
        for (int index_2 = 0; index_2 < width; index_2++)
        {
            std::cin >> matrix[index_1][index_2];
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Матрица получилась: " << '\n';

    print_array(width, height, matrix);

    for(int i = 0; i < height; ++ i)
        delete[] matrix[i];
    delete[] matrix;

}
```